# XCODE: How to save button image after change?

Tags: xcode4

UPDATED----

Ok, so I've found a way to do it....may not be the right way, but I'm new to xcode and this way seems to have worked for me. Maybe someone out there can improve on the idea.

The original question was how to save a button image after it has been changed? Ok, well here goes....I have a custom button set up with an image, so the first thing I did was change the image for that button using this code: (btw it is set up so that you click one button to change the image of the custom button)

```
.h file

@interface viewcontroller{

IBOutlet UIButton *btnSetImage1;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSetImage1;
```

Then the code:

```
.m file

@synthesize btnSetImage1;

//Inside a button's action

UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_green.png"];
        [btnSetImage1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

-----------------------HERE'S WHERE THE QUESTION GETS ANSWERED------------------------------

Ok, so now that the image is changed on the custom button, I saved it by adding this:

```
    .h file

@interface viewcontroller{

IBOutlet UIButton *btnSetImage1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonImgChange1;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSetImage1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonImgChange1;
```

Then the code:

```
.m file

@synthesize btnSetImage1;
@synthesize buttonImgChange1;

//Inside a button's action

UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_green.png"];
        [btnSetImage1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

//Set image to variable  

buttonImgChange1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:btnImage1];

        //SAVE CHANGES

        // Create instances of NSData
        UIImage *savedButtonImage1 = buttonImgChange1.image;
        NSData *buttonData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedButtonImage1);    
        // Store the data
        NSUserDefaults *buttondefaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [buttondefaults1 setObject:buttonData1 forKey:@"buttonImage1"];

        [buttondefaults1 synchronize];
```

With that I was able to save the button image as a key called "buttonImage1". Then I just called for this key in the viewdidload:

```
//-----------UPDATE BUTTONS---------------


// Get the stored data before the view loads
NSUserDefaults *buttondefaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSData *buttonData1 = [buttondefaults1 dataForKey:@"buttonImage1"];
UIImage *savedButtonImage1 = [UIImage imageWithData:buttonData1];


// Update the UI elements with the saved data
buttonImgChange1.image = savedButtonImage1;


//Update buttons
UIImage *btnImage1 = savedButtonImage1;
[btnSetImage1 setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

buttonImgChange1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:btnImage1];
```

Like I said...I'm new to xcode and looked all over for a solution to this question. After fumbling through it myself I came up with this solution. It may not be the best or most efficient, I don't know, but it worked for me and I hope it helps someone else along the way.

Oh, and just a note, if you want two different images, one that shows in the buttons normal state and then a different one when the button is clicked, simply copy all the code and rename all the variables, the forKey name, and finally change the forState to - forState:UIControlStateHighlighted. And there you have it, a button that when pressed changes and saves a custom button's image.

Thanks!

Comment: What change are you talking about?

Comment: I have 2 custom buttons which are images. With the above code I changed their images to button_up.png and the other to button_down.png. When I close the simulator in xcode and open it back up, the button images revert back to the original images. I want to save them as button_up and button_down. Thanks Deepak.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! Soon as I clean it up a bit, I'll post the code for anyone else that comes across this thread. Thanks!